# Application of weaker form of Brunn-Minkowski inequality

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry, geometric-inequalities

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider two compact subsets $A,\ B$. If $V$ is a volume form, then $$ V(A+B)^\frac{1}{n}\geq V(A)^\frac{1}{n} + V(B)^\frac{1}{n}\tag {1}$$ which is called **Brunn-Minkowski inequality**, where $sA+tB :=\{sx+ty|x\in A,\ y\in B\}$.

As an application, we have an **isoperimetric inequality**.

For $0<t<1$, by (1) together with arithmetric mean - geometric mean inequality, $$ V((1-t)A + tB)\geq V(A)^{1-t} V(B)^t \tag {2}$$

If $f,\ g,\ m$ are characteristic functions on $A,\ B,\ (1-t)A + tB$, then $$ m((1-t)x+ty)\geq f(x)^{1-t} g(y)^{t} \tag {3}$$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. And $(2)$ can be rewritten by $$ \int m(a) da \geq \bigg(\int f(a)da\bigg)^{1-t}\bigg(\int g(a)da \bigg)^t \tag {4}$$

Here **Prekopa-Leindler inequality** is : Any functions satisfying (3) have (4).

**Question** : Is there an application of Prekopa-Leindler inequality ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a beautiful review paper by R.J. Gardner: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2002-39-03/S0273-0979-02-00941-2/

Comment: @Rigel Thank you very much.

Comment: See chapter 8 of http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf